# Unable to retrieve object from constructor function when running Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to access my own JS module when running Cypress tests. I have defined my own module as...

```
cy.companies = function () {
    const Company = function () {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = "";
    };

    return {
        Company: function () {
            return Company;
        }
    };
}();
```

I have then modified \support\index.js to include this file...

```
import "../fixtures/provisioning/companies";
```

Then inside \support\commands.js I have added...

```
Cypress.Commands.add("createCompany", () => {
    return new cy.companies.Company();
});
```

So that's the setup. I then consume it like this...

```
describe("...", () => {
    beforeEach(function () {
        const company = cy.createCompany();
        console.log(company)
    });
});
```

In the console I would expect to see...

```
{  
    id: 0,  
    name: ""  
}
```

...but what I actually see is...

```
$Chainer {userInvocationStack: "    at Context.eval (https://[...]/__cy…press\integration\[...].spec.js:54:22)", specWindow: Window, chainerId: "chainer2", firstCall: false,   useInitialStack: false}
chainerId: "chainer2"
firstCall: false
...
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You don't need to use a custom command for this, just call your constructor directly inside the beforeEach(), i.e `const company = new cy.companies.Company()`. Custom commands are for injecting into the command queue, which is why you are seeing the chainer wrapper in the console.

Comment: If submitted as an answer then I'll mark it as _Accepted_.

Answer (score 1):

First issue is in your js module:

```
cy.companies = (function () {
    const Company = function () {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = name;
    };

  /*  return {
        Company: function () {
            return Company;
        }
    }; */
    return { Company };
})();
```

Second issue is due to the fact: `cy commands are asynchronous and are queued to be run later`, so you need to use `.then`

```
describe("...", () => {
    beforeEach(function () {
    //  const company = cy.createCompany();
    //  console.log(company)
        cy.createCompany().then((company) => {
          cy.log(company);
          console.log(company);
        });

    });
});
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the two suggestions. Your first suggestion - regarding the JS module - assumes that `Conpany` is the only member exposed by the module (granted, in my example this is true). And your second suggestion is correct but I've opted for the simpler approach of calling the module without adding a custom command.

Comment: Yes that made more sense :)